# Keep permission to folder for next session

Tags: c#, permissions, uwp, directory

I grant access to a specific folder using FolderPicker

```
FolderPicker picker = new FolderPicker();

picker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
StorageFolder folder = await picker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
```

After that app have permissions to read, create files in this specific directory. After restart app lose it's permissions. How to keep it for next session?

Comment: You need to use [StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.accesscache.storageapplicationpermissions.futureaccesslist).

Comment: @MehrzadChehraz what about create an answer here for this, it should be an answer.

Comment: @BarryWang-MSFT I guess the question is a duplicate, I create an answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.accesscache.storageapplicationpermissions.futureaccesslist) which returns an instance of [StorageItemAccessList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.accesscache.storageitemaccesslist) object to keep the access to a file or folder for future.

> Gets an object that represents a list that an app maintains so that
>   the app can store files and/or locations (like folders) and easily
>   access these items in the future.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.accesscache.storageitemaccesslist) is an example to add an item to the list:

```
StorageFile file = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
if (file != null)
{
    // Add to FA without metadata
    string faToken = StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(file);  
}
```

Later, you can use the token to get an instance to the item:

```
var storageItem = await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetItemAsync(faToken);
```

Be aware that the list of future access list is limited.

> This list can store up to 1000 items and must be maintained by the
>   app.